# What is the impact factor of EPJ Web of Conference?

Tags: journals, conference, impact-factor

The journal [EPJ Web of Conference](https://www.epj-conferences.org/) is indexed in many databases: DOAJ, EBSCO, CAS, SCOPUS, etc., but I cannot find its impact factor. Does anyone know it?

Comment: What an awkward name for a journal. It sounds made up to me.

Comment: @CapeCode It is a real journal though.

Answer (score 2):

According to their Homepage this journal is supposed to be listed in Clarivate Analytics' Databases, Web of Science and Journal Citation Reports, but I cannot find it there. The are some EPJ Journals indexed in WoS. The one you are looking for is apparently not. The only EPJ journal indexed in the JCR is EPJ Data Science by SpringerOpen. As EPJ Web of Conferences seems not to be indexed in the JCR at the moment, it should not have an Impact Factor.

Comment: Thank you! I also looked at these databases without finding anything useful.